# How many combinations can 2 different groups have

Tags: permutations

So for example if we had A B and C and 1, 2 and 3 how many different group of 3 Letter/Number pairs can we make with no repetition as in,

A1 B1 C1

A1 B1 C2

A1 B1 C3

A1 B2 C1 etc…

By simply doing it I know the answer is 27 but I wonder if there is a general way to do it as in if x = letter and j=
Number how many different x,j combinations can you have

So essentially:

how many different X,J pairs can you make when x= [x1,x2,x3] and J=[j1,j2,j3]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See my comments following the answer of mrtwhs.  Unclear if this is what you are asking.

Comment: You have counted (A1,B1,C1), but have you counted (A1,A2,A3)?

Answer (score 0):

A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3

You specifically asked for "how many different Letter/Number pairs can we make".  There are nine. ...unless of course you meant something else.

Comment: You are right sorry, edited comment to better explain my question